# Weblogic manage node not coming up

Tags: weblogic11g

I am getting below error while starting one of the manage node in my cluster. There are around 6 manage node and the other 5 are coming up fine. However  one node is giving below error. Can someone let me know where i need to look for the cause of this.

```
<Mar 3, 2017 9:26:10 AM CST> <Error> <Deployer> <WL-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application 'apsp-ear-trp'.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Could not setup environment
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activateContexts(WebAppModule.java:1516)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activate(WebAppModule.java:444)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:375)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:95)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentException: [J2EE:160101]Error: The ejb-link 'UserManager' declared in the ejb-ref or ejb-local-ref 'ejb/UserManager' in the application module 'admin-tools.war' could not be resolved. The target EJB for the ejb-ref could not be found. Please ensure the link is correct.
at weblogic.deployment.BaseEnvironmentBuilder.addEJBLinkRef(BaseEnvironmentBuilder.java:469)
at weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentBuilder.addEJBReferences(EnvironmentBuilder.java:496)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.CompEnv.activate(CompEnv.java:157)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.activate(WebAppServletContext.java:3164)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activateContexts(WebAppModule.java:1514)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

<Mar 3, 2017 9:26:10 AM CST> <Error> <Deployer> <WL-149250> <Unable to unprepare application 'apsp-ear-trp'.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/event/EventListeners$2
at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.destroyListeners(EventListeners.java:215)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:850)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.close(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:46)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.close(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:656)
at weblogic.deployment.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.close(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:19)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/event/EventListeners$2
at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.destroyListeners(EventListeners.java:215)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:850)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.close(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:46)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.close(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:656)
at weblogic.deployment.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.close(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:19)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: all is said in your logs. Weblogic is not able to deploy your application because it cannot resolve an ejb from the web app admin-tools.war